# Proper way to insert HTML into Flask

Tags: python, html, flask, insert

I know how to send some plain text from Python with render_template when a URL is visited:

```
@app.route(/success.html")
...
return render_template("index.html", text="This text goes inside the HTML")
```

And the template would have something like this:

```
<div class="output">
  {{text|safe}}
 </div>
```

However, I am not sure what to do when I need to insert a few lines of HTML. For example, a form:

```
<form action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">I have a car 
</form>
```

It will probably work if I load this as a string in the Python script and send it to the template, but that doesn't sound quite right.

Anyone knows how to properly insert HTML into a Flask webpage? A dummy example would also be great.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> I want to figure out how to insert a HTML snippet into an existing template...

You can use the Jinja2 [`{% include %}`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#include) directive.

```
{% include 'your_form.html' %}
```

> ... and where to store that snippet.

So you'd put your form in a template of its own, called `your_form.html` with the content:

```
<form action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">I have a car 
</form>
```

then in your `index.html` include it

```
<div class="output">
  {% include 'your_form.html' %}
 </div>
```

### Dynamic variables in Jinja2

> I want to render it dynamically.

Quoting from the [docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#variables)

> If you access variables inside tags don’t put the braces around them.

So simply:

```
{% include html_file %}
```

**If you're using older versions, here's a simple way**

```
{% include '%s' % html_file %}
```

Just to illustrate the flexibility of it, here's some examples to give you inspiration

```
{% include '%s.html' % name_without_extension %}
{% include 'templates/%s/forms/%s' % (company, template) %}
```

**You can also set a Jinja variable like this (it's more verbose IMO)**

```
{% set template_path = html_file %}
{% include template_path %}
```

**Security tip:** Make sure you know exactly what is passed on as the variable `html_file`, since it's dynamic, if that value comes from the client, you may be exposing your own files

Comment: That works perfectly except it loads when index.html loads. I want to render it dynamically. I tried `{% include html_file %}` and then         `render_template("index.html",  html_file='download.html')` but that didn't work.

Comment: I have Jinja 2.8, and getting this error `jinja2.exceptions.TemplatesNotFound: Tried to select from an empty list of templates.`
I was able to fix it by modifying the directive to `{% include txt ignore missing %}`. My render_template looks like this `return render_template("index.html", txt='download.html')`. So, the HTML snippet is showing now. I just don't understand the missing template error I get when not inluding `ignore missing`

Answer (score -1):

Flask uses the [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/) template engine (both have the same developer), and when `render_template("filename", "content")` is used will look for templates with that filename in the templates folder.
If your application is a module, this folder should be next to that module, like so:

```
/application.py
/templates
    /hello.html
```

If it’s a package it needs to be inside your package, like so:

```
/application
    /__init__.py
    /templates
        /hello.html
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not exactly what I was asking. I know how to render a template. I want to figure out how to insert a HTML snippet into an existing template and where to store that snippet.

Comment: ahh, you can use the tempting engine to store the snippet in a separate template and then insert the render from that into the main one

Answer (score -1):

Template inheritance may also be useful for html reuse. You can add a base template and add custom html codes/blocks to the child html codes.

> Base Template:
>
> ```
> <!doctype html>
> <html>
>   <head>
>     {% block head %}
>     <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
>     <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} - My Webpage</title>
>     {% endblock %}
>   </head>
>   <body>
>     <div id="content">{% block content %}{% endblock %}</div>
>     <div id="footer">
>       {% block footer %}
>       &copy; Copyright 2010 by <a href="http://domain.invalid/">you</a>.
>       {% endblock %}
>     </div>
>   </body>
> </html>
> ```
>
> Child Template:
>
> ```
> {% extends "layout.html" %}
> {% block title %}Index{% endblock %}
> {% block head %}
>   {{ super() }}
>   <style type="text/css">
>     .important { color: #336699; }
>   </style>
> {% endblock %}
> {% block content %}
>   <h1>Index</h1>
>   <p class="important">
>     Welcome on my awesome homepage.
> {% endblock %}
> ```

source: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/templateinheritance/

Answer (score -2):

You can load it as a string in python
But you should have your web-server(apache?) handle that

Comment: Not using Apache, but what do you mean by that? I just need to figure out where to write that HTML form and how to send and receive it in the index.html page.

Comment: Well usually I have a web server before reaching my python. If you only have python flask then something like
    `with open('htmlfile.html','r') as f:
        return Response(f.read(),mimetype='text/xml')`

Comment: I thought there would be some jinja2 methods there.